# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'

Tags: python, pandas, function, class

I want to call `df["ID"]` in the `dataset_csv` function and then call the `dataset_csv` function using `dataset = RawToCSV.dataset_csv(input_path)`. `df["ID"]` was defined in the `raw_file_processing` function.
My code raised `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'` error.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np

input_path = "../input_data"


class RawToCSV:

    def __init__(self, path_, df):
        self.measurement_df = None
        self.cls = None
        self.path_ = path_
        self.df = df

    def raw_file_processing(self, path_):

        # Open all the subfolders within path
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_):
            for file in files:
                with open(os.path.join(root, file), "r") as data:
                    self.df = pd.read_csv(data)

                    # 'Class' refers to the independent variable
                    cls_info = self.df.iloc[2]

                    # Dummy-code the classes
                    cls = pd.get_dummies(cls_info)

                    # Create the ID series by concatenating columns 1-3
                    self.df = self.df.assign(
                        ID=self.df[['cell_id:cell_id', 'region:region', 'tile_num:tile_num']].apply(
                            lambda row: '_'.join([str(each) for each in row]), axis=1))
                    self.df = self.df.drop(columns=['cell_id:cell_id', 'region:region', 'tile_num:tile_num'])

                    # Obtain measurement info
                    # Normalize data against blank/empty columns
                    # log-transform the data
                    for col in self.df[9:]:
                        if re.findall(r"Blank|Empty", col):
                            background = col
                        else:
                            line = col.readline()
                            for dat in line:
                                norm_data = dat / background
                                self.measurement_df = np.log2(norm_data)

        return self.df["ID"], cls, self.measurement_df

    def dataset_csv(self):
        """Col 1: ID
        Col 2: class
        Col 3-n: measurements"""
        ids = self.df["ID"]
        id_col = ids.to_frame()

        cls_col = self.cls.to_frame()
        frames = [id_col, cls_col, self.measurement_df]
        dataset_df = pd.concat(frames)
        data_csv = dataset_df.to_csv("../input_data/dataset.csv")

        return data_csv

raw = RawToCSV(input_path)
three_tuple = raw.raw_file_processing(input_path)
dataset = raw.data_csv()
```

Traceback:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) /tmp/ipykernel_136/323215226.py in <module>
> ----> 1 raw = RawToCSV(input_path)
>       2 three_tuple = raw.raw_file_processing(input_path)
> 
> TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'
```

Comment: can you explain the line `self.df = self.df` ?

Comment: I've already answered your question, dear melololo.

Answer (score 1):

In this part of code:

```py
dataset = RawToCSV.dataset_csv(input_path)
```

You are using the class itself, however you should first instantiate from the class `RawToCSV`, like this:

```py
rawToCSV = RawTOCSV(input_path)
dataset = rawToCSV.data_csv()
```

But still you have another mistake ,too. In the constructor of the class , `__init__` you've initiated the `self.df` with `self.df`, which the latter one hasn't been defined ,yet.
Therefore in this part of code, you'll get another error (`AttributeError: 'RawToCSV' object has no attribute 'df'`):

```py
def __init__(self, path_):
        self.measurement_df = None
        self.cls = None
        self.path_ = path_
        self.df = self.df     #  <-----
```

Comment: I've edited the __init__ function to initialize `self.df = df` but now its raising `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'`. Please refer to the edited question and traceback. thanks

Comment: You should pass the `df` to the constructor, like this:  `rawToCSV = RawTOCSV(input_path, df)`. make sure you've defined the `df` variable, before passing it.

Comment: How do I define `df`? Its defined within the `raw_file_processing` function as `self.df_ = pd.read_csv(data)` but I still get `name 'df' is not defined`  error.

Comment: You don't need to define the `df` in the `__init__`, you can just define it in the  `raw_file_processing` function (you don't need to change `raw_file_processing` funtion). Just remove the `self.df = df` from `__init__`  also remove the `df` from arguments that `__init__` takes, like this: `__init__(self, path_)`.

Comment: Hi @melololo , How are you doing? Have your problem got solved? Is my answer useful and helpful for you? if so , I'll be so delighted if you give my answer an upvote  or even choose it as the correct answer ✅. Cheers. 

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```py
dataset = RawToCSV.dataset_csv(input_path)
```

you're calling `dataset_csv` as if it were a static method (calling it on the class not an instance). You are passing in `input_path`, which I assume is a string. Since you're calling the method as if it were static, it is not invisibly adding the actual `self` value into the call (you have to have an object to even be sent as `self`).

This means that your one parameter of `dataset_csv`, which you named `self`, is receiving the (string) value of `input_path`.

The error message is telling you that the string `input_path` has no member `.df` because it doesn't.

With the way your class and its methods are currently set up, you'll need your entry point code at the bottom to be something like this:

```py
raw = RawToCSV(input_path)
three_tuple = raw.raw_file_processing(input_path)
dataset = raw.dataset_csv()
```

Though, you may want to restructure your class and its methods